# String to date in Pervasive view

Tags: psql, pervasive

I created a view in Pervasive Control Center.
This view has a column "WeegDatum" which is a string (CHAR type) with a DDMMYYYY date.
I'm trying to convert this to a date.

My only experience with creating Pervasive views is selecting and filtering data.
I've tried all i could find over the last two days.
Mainly variations on `"TO_DATE(,)"` but nothing seems to work.

Just the (working) view:

```
CREATE VIEW "TEST2" AS SELECT "IORegHis" ."WeegDatum" FROM "IORegHis" "IORegHis"

View trying to convert to date:

CREATE VIEW "TEST2" AS SELECT TO_DATE('"IORegHis" ."WeegDatum"','DDMMYYYY') FROM "IORegHis" "IORegHis"
```

This gives me `"Error in expression: To_DATE"`
I won't name all the syntax errors I have gotten the last days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pervasive Date format is 'yyyy-mm-dd'.
You'll need to use something like this to convert your 'DDMMYYYY' to the Date format and then convert it to a SQL_DATE type:

```
select 
CONVERT(right(WeegDatum,4) + '-'+ 
        right(left(WeegDatum,4),2) + '-' + 
        left (WeegDatum,2), SQL_DATE)  
from IORegHis
```

Comment: Thank you, this works!


```"CONVERT"' ("RIGHT" ("IORegHis" ."WeegDatum" ,4 )+'-' +"RIGHT" ("LEFT" ("IORegHis" ."WeegDatum" ,4 ),2 )+'-' +"LEFT" ("IORegHis" ."WeegDatum" ,2 ),"SQL_DATE" )```

Comment: To late to save my edit:

Somehow Pervasive puts everyting in quotations after I save the view, but it doesn't seem to give any problems.